# How to restrict web service to Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

Hello I wanted to request api keys (client ids, application ids, etc) from a web service under a .NET web application that I created. The thing is I need to make this web service secure, in other words only the downloaded app on wp7 should be able to request this web service. Is there some kind of device specific string that I can authenticate against to make sure a WP7 device is calling this?

The reason I am doing this is in case the key ever gets compromised, I can change it from within my web application without having to update the app on every single device the app was downloaded to.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any device specific string can be spoofed and WP7 doesn't have a secure storage method today.  A common scheme is to return an authentication token from an https login method that is then stored on the device as an encrypted stream.  Realize that the decryption key and string are both on the device and could be decrypted if the device is compromised.  You can also then expire the authentication tokens server-side whenever you need to and the tokens can expire after a certain time.

Comment: I agree. As long as the client has access to the code, they can hack it. But it's probably sufficient to have a "good enough" security in this scenario.

Comment: So is it even worth calling it from a web service? Or is it better just to store it inside the application encrypted?

Comment: You don't want to store the key in your application if it needs to be "rotated" on a regular basis.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly the key returned from the web service is encrypted. And inside the application contains a key to decrypt the encrypted key returned from the web service?

Comment: Consider the key returned from the web service an "access token" that needs to be passed with every subsequent call to the service - the access token is associated with a user being granted access to the service.  You should store that access token in isolated storage as an encrypted stream.  You still need to have the decryption key locally on your phone - and that is your weak link.  There is no way around that currently.